# I have a python script that works perfectly in the Thonny IDE, but fails in terminal

Tags: python-3.x, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, pexpect

Firstly, here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import re, pexpect, os

file = '/home/homebridge/flags/Restart.flag'
f = open(file, 'w')
f.close()
os.system("sudo systemctl stop homebridge")
os.system("sudo chmod -R a+rwx /var/lib/homebridge")
child = pexpect.spawn('tuya-cli wizard')
child.expect('\r\n')
child.sendline('y')
child.expect('\r\n')
child.sendline('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
data = child.read()
data = data.decode("utf-8")
devices = data.split('},')
devicesO = []
class device:
    name = ""
    ID = ""
    key = ""
    
    def __init__(self, name, ID, key):
        self.name = name
        self.ID = ID
        self.key = key
        
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.name < other.name

for i in devices:


    n = re.search("name: \'(.*)\'", str(i)).group(1)
    I = re.search("id: \'(.*)\'", str(i)).group(1)
    k = re.search("key: \'(.*)\'", str(i)).group(1)
    if n != ("Clock"):
        devicesO.append(device(n, I, k))

entries = []
devicesO.sort()
for device in devicesO:
    if "phone charger" not in device.name:
        s1 = "{\n\"name\": \"" + device.name + "\",\n\"id\": \"" + device.ID + "\",\n\"key\": \"" + device.key + "\","
        s2 = """
"type": "RGBTWLight",
"manufacturer": "SmartLife",
"model": "Light",
"dpPower": "20",
"dpMode": "21",
"dpBrightness": "22",
"dpColorTemperature": "23",
"dpColor": "24",
"colorFunction": "HSB",
"scaleBrightness": 1000
}"""
    else:
        s1 = "{\n\"name\": \"" + device.name + "\",\n\"id\": \"" + device.ID + "\",\n\"key\": \"" + device.key + "\","
        s2 = """
"type": "Outlet",
"manufacturer": "SmartLife",
"model": "Outlet",
"dpPower": "1"
}"""
    entries.append(s1 + s2)
string = ",\n".join([str(entry) for entry in entries])
config = open('/var/lib/homebridge/config.json', 'r+')
x = config.read()
config.close()
#print(x)
x = re.sub("\"TuyaLan\",\n.*\"devices\": \[((.|\n)*?)\]", "\"TuyaLan\",\n\"devices\": [\n" + string + "\n]", x)
#print(x)
#x = re.sub("\"TuyaLan\",\n.*\"devices\": \[((.|\n)*?)\]", "\"TuyaLan\",\n.*\"devices\": [\nTEST\n]", x)
config = open('/var/lib/homebridge/config.json', 'w+')
config.write(x)
config.close()
config = open('/var/lib/homebridge/config.json', 'r+')
print (config.read())
config.close()
os.remove(file)
os.system("sudo systemctl restart homebridge")
```

This executes as expected in the IDE, stopping the homebridge service, pulling relevant data from the tuya-cli utility, regex and text replacement, all of it. However, when I try and run it in the terminal without sudo, the first regex search returns an empty object and the script fails. When I run it *with* sudo, it stalls for a while then times out on the pexpect step at the beginning. I've researched before posting, but I have no clue how to solve this one. It doesn't appear to be a path issue, I used pip3 to install both re and pexpect, and os is obviously packaged with the raspbian install. Any clues would be great.
Error without sudo:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ /home/homebridge/scripts/updateConfig.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/homebridge/scripts/updateConfig.py", line 34, in <module>
    n = re.search("name: \'(.*)\'", str(i)).group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

With sudo:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo /home/homebridge/scripts/updateConfig.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/homebridge/scripts/updateConfig.py", line 10, in <module>
    child.expect('\r\n')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 344, in expect
    timeout, searchwindowsize, async_)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 372, in expect_list
    return exp.expect_loop(timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pexpect/expect.py", line 181, in expect_loop
    return self.timeout(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pexpect/expect.py", line 144, in timeout
    raise exc
pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT: Timeout exceeded.
<pexpect.pty_spawn.spawn object at 0x766c4510>
command: /usr/bin/tuya-cli
args: ['/usr/bin/tuya-cli', 'wizard']
buffer (last 100 chars): b'\x1b[32m?\x1b[39m \x1b[1mThe API key from tuya.com:\x1b[22m\x1b[0m \x1b[0m\x1b[29D\x1b[29C'
before (last 100 chars): b'\x1b[32m?\x1b[39m \x1b[1mThe API key from tuya.com:\x1b[22m\x1b[0m \x1b[0m\x1b[29D\x1b[29C'
after: <class 'pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT'>
match: None
match_index: None
exitstatus: None
flag_eof: False
pid: 1470
child_fd: 5
closed: False
timeout: 30
delimiter: <class 'pexpect.exceptions.EOF'>
logfile: None
logfile_read: None
logfile_send: None
maxread: 2000
ignorecase: False
searchwindowsize: None
delaybeforesend: 0.05
delayafterclose: 0.1
delayafterterminate: 0.1
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compile(b'\r\n')
```

Comment: Is it possible that the IDE is using python2?

Comment: Good thought, but no, Thonny uses 3.7.

Comment: You're saying that the regex match fails, but you don't understand why. A great first step is finding out what the string you're trying to match against is. You can do this with `print` statements. By putting `print(str(i))` immediately before the regex match, Python will show the string in the terminal.

Comment: Yes, I’ve gone through that already. As I said, when run in the IDE, the regex match *does not* fail, and works perfectly. Regex is not passed a string at all outside of the IDE. The issue here is not the code itself, it’s something about the environment.

Comment: It's generally much easier to find out what's wrong, and from there determine the differences in the environment that made that happen. If you still prefer to go the other way, you can add a `time.sleep(3600)` to your program, run it in the IDE, find it's pid, then dump its environment via `/proc/yourpid/environ` and examine the state of stdin/out/err via `/proc/yourpid/fd/*`. If you then run your Python script with the same environment and streams of the same type, you would hopefully see the same result.

Comment: Your advice was sound, I went back and added in some print statements to narrow down the search. Pexpect was interacting oddly with tuya-cli outside of the IDE. Now I have that working, but the regex is still not matching outside of the IDE. The string is being passed as expected to the loop, and I can print it fine, but I'm still getting 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'. Still, thank you for your help so far!

Comment: Alright, stranger and stranger. The code: print('Regex test: ' + str(re.search("name: ....", str(i)))) inside the IDE returns as expected, <re.Match object; match="name: 'Liv"> but from the terminal it returns <re.Match object; match="name: \x1b[32'">

Comment: I've found a workaround by changing the regex to search more liberally, but I'd still love to know why the editor is getting a clean string and the terminal is getting old escape characters.

Answer (score 0):

***Possible short answer:*** Your IDE is probably automatically adding carriage returns with your sendlines, which is why your code runs in the IDE, but not at the terminal. Sendline adds a line feed (`\n`), but not a carriage return (`\r`). You should add a `\r` after each sendline (e.g., `child.sendline('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\r')`) to complete the CRLF (`\r\n`).

***Long explanation:***

Based on your code, when you spawned the child, you expected a CRLF. However, pexpect searches are not greedy and will stop at the first CRLF they encounter. Unfortunately, when I tested your code, pexpect stopped at the CRLF after the command you entered, not the prompt afterwards:

```
child = pexpect.spawn('tuya-cli wizard')
child.expect('\r\n')
print(child.before)
```

**Output**

`b" tuya-cli wizard"`

You should be looking for a prompt or a message instead, such as `The API key from tuya.com:` or `Password:`:

```
# tuya-cli wizard
The API key from tuya.com:
The API secret from tuya.com:
Provide a 'virtual ID' of a device currently registered in the app:
```

or

```
# sudo tuya-cli wizard
Password:
```

However, I think both of your errors occurred because you did not include a carriage return (`\r`) with your sendlines. The first error occurred because, at the prompt, `The API key from tuya.com:`, you sent 'y', not 'y\r', so nothing was entered at the prompt. You then searched for CRLF, but since you had not included a `\r`, pexpect found the original CRLF after `b" tuya-cli wizard"`.

The expect call actually caused a carriage return, but, unfortunately, your code was now a step behind, and was interacting with the previous prompt, not the current prompt. That is why `data = child.read()` ended up reading the wrong output, resulting in a `NoneType` object.

The second error occurred because the pexpect cursor moved up to the `The API key from tuya.com:` prompt, looking for a CRLF. Since it is a prompt, it does not end with a CRLF, so the pexpect search timed out (those `\x1b` escape sequences are just for formatting and color):

```
pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT: Timeout exceeded.
args: ['/usr/bin/tuya-cli', 'wizard']
before (last 100 chars): b'\x1b[32m?\x1b[39m \x1b[1mThe API key from tuya.com:\x1b[22m\x1b[0m \x1b[0m\x1b[29D\x1b[29C'
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compile(b'\r\n')
```

Note that there is no `\r\n` in the `buffer` or `before` byte strings.

I would do something like:

```
...
while True:
    index = child.expect(
        ["Password:", "The API key from tuya.com:", pexpect.TIMEOUT, pexpect.EOF, ])
    if index == 0:
        password = getpass()  # You will need 'from getpass import getpass'
        child.sendline(password)  # CR's are usually not needed with variables
    elif index == 1:
        # This is what you want
        child.sendline("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\r")
        break
    elif index == 2:
        raise RuntimeError("Search string not found.")
    elif index ==3:
        raise RuntimeError("Child closed.")

child.expect("The API secret from tuya.com:")
child.sendline("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\r")
...
```

Good luck with your code!